# SQL Server: Creating weighted score with current query

Tags: sql-server

The query below returns a calculated `TotalScore` by grabbing the most recent score for that last 6 months including the current month. The `TotalScore` is calculated by adding various "scores" from several columns from table `ProviderValueCard` for a paticular ProviderID. Currently 30 is added to the score if `SessionsProgress` is > 1. It needs to be instead scaled to if SessionsProgress is 0 +0, 1 then +10, 2 +20, 3 +20, 4 +30, 5 +30.

```
    DECLARE @ProviderID INT, @Now DATETIME, @Months INT

SELECT @Now = GETDATE(), @Months = 6;

WITH 
date_range_cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS RowNum, DATEADD(mm,-1,@Now) AS StartDate, DATEADD(mm,0,@Now) AS EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.RowNum + 1 AS RowNum, DATEADD(mm,(-d.RowNum - 1),@Now) AS StartDate, DATEADD(mm,-d.RowNum,@Now) AS EndDate
    FROM date_range_cte d
    WHERE d.RowNum + 1 <= @Months
    ),
    main_cte AS (
            SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ProviderID, d.RowNum, d.EndDate ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC) AS ordinal_position,
            a.ProviderID, 
            d.RowNum, 
            d.EndDate,
            [AdditionalReports] * 5 AS AdditionalReports,
            [UniqueReportRequests] * 15 AS UniqueReportsRequests,
            [SessionsProgress] * 30 as SurveyCompleted,
            CASE WHEN b.ProviderID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 50 END as SubscriptionExists
            FROM ProviderValueCard a
            INNER JOIN date_range_cte d ON d.StartDate < Time_Stamp AND Time_Stamp <= d.EndDate 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SubscriptionsTV b ON a.ProviderID = b.ProviderID  
            --WHERE a.ProviderID = @ProviderID AND GroupID = 2
            WHERE a.ProviderID = 1672 AND GroupID = 2
            )  
        SELECT ProviderID, RowNum, EndDate, (AdditionalReports + UniqueReportsRequests + SurveyCompleted + SubscriptionExists) AS TotalScore
        FROM main_cte
        WHERE ordinal_position = 1
        ORDER BY RowNum
```

Current Output

```
ProviderID  RowNum      EndDate                 TotalScore
----------- ----------- ----------------------- -----------
1672        1           2015-02-12 10:09:27.420 100
1672        2           2015-01-12 10:09:27.420 70
1672        3           2014-12-12 10:09:27.420 70
1672        4           2014-11-12 10:09:27.420 55
1672        5           2014-10-12 10:09:27.420 70
1672        6           2014-09-12 10:09:27.420 55
```

Feburary entry for first row score from table ProviderValueCard. SessionsProgess = 1, so Feb score for above is giving full 30 but needs to only give 10 instead for a score of 80, not 100.

```
ProviderID  AdditionalReports UniqueReportRequests Time_Stamp              AdditionalReportsNum UniqueReportsNum SessionsProgress AdditionalReportsNumQtr UniqueReportsNumQtr SurveyCompleted
----------- ----------------- -------------------- ----------------------- -------------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------------- ------------------- ---------------
1672        1                 1                    2015-02-06 11:38:37.680 130                  6                1                0                       1                   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CASE [SessionsProgress] WHEN 1 THEN 10
                                WHEN 2 THEN 20
                                WHEN 3 THEN 20
                                WHEN 4 THEN 30
                                WHEN 5 THEN 30
                                ELSE 0
         END as SurveyCompleted,
```